# animation-list with scale tag not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, xml, animation, scale, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an animation-list xml drawable `anim_progress.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:duration="100"> 
        <scale android:drawable="@drawable/frame_1" android:scaleGravity="center"/> 
    </item>

    <item android:duration="100"> 
        <scale android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2" android:scaleGravity="center"/> 
    </item>

    <item android:duration="100"> 
        <scale android:drawable="@drawable/frame_3" android:scaleGravity="center"/> 
    </item>

    .
    .
    .

</animation-list>
```

I use `scale` tag because the images `frame_x.png` are larger than a container view. The reason for that is the ability to suit most screen sizes.

I use this frame animation as an `indeterminateDrawable` of my custom ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/anim_progress"
    />
```

It works OK in Android versions before Marshmallow. I have checked emulators and devices.
But in Marshmallow it just shows nothing. Blank empty space. As well as the preview pane in the Android Studio.

If i remove the `scale` tag from the `animation-list`, it works well in Marshmallow, and scales itself the right way, but appears to be cropped in other Android versions.

I know that i can make separate file in `drawable-v23` folder, nut before that i wanted to ask if someone can share other technique of scaling the progress bar frame animation drawable in Marshmallow via xml.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I have no idea why it's not working in Marhmallow but the work around is to use rotate as the intermediatDrawable and not an animation-list.

Something like this:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="250"
android:fromDegrees="359"
android:toDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:drawable="@drawable/icn_refresh">
</rotate>
```

Comment: yep, rotate will work, but its not a work around for animation-list :) i my case i have a frame by frame animation of a non rotating objects, so rotate will not help.

Answer (score 0):

We also ran into this problem when running on Marshmallow. A co-worker pointed out it could be fixed by modifying the xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_1"/> 

    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2"/> 

    <item android:duration="100" android:drawable="@drawable/frame_3"/> 

    .
    .
    .

</animation-list>
```

I don't know why this fixes the problem. For you, if the `android:scaleGravity` attribute is necessary you may need to re-add it.